# How to search work item (bug) in azure devops using api without using bug id or title

Tags: azure-devops, devops

I am using this api to fetch bug from devops org work item

```
$api = "https://{0}.almsearch.visualstudio.com/{1}/_apis/search/workItemQueryResults?api-version=5.1-preview" -f $OrganizationName, $ProjectName

$body = '{"searchText":"Title: my xyz title here","skipResults":0,"takeResults":2,"sortOptions":[],"summarizedHitCountsNeeded":true,"searchFilters":{"Projects":["myprojectname"],"Work Item Types":["Bug"],"States":["Active","New"]},"filters":[],"includeSuggestions":false}' | ConvertFrom-Json

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method POST -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $userlogintoken)} -Body $body
```

I don't have bug id.

I don't want to use title and tag or description, repro steps in searchtext to query bug from DevOps.

Are there any fields where I can put some unique value while creating bug then while searching I can use that value to search for a particular bug?

(i am creating bug using my script. before creating I need to query in DevOps whether the same bug is not already present then only create new)

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: You can have a try creating a [custom field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/add-custom-field?view=azure-devops) for bug work item type. Then you can use this custom field to search for the bug.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to query in DevOps whether the same bug is not already present
> then only create new

For this issue, I am afraid there should be no other fields except titile, tag, discussion, repro steps that can be used as query conditions to search for a particular bug. In these special fields, we can add specific descriptions as query conditions, but this cannot be achieved in other given fields.

As workaround, you can create a custom field for the bug item in the Process of the organization settings. About how to add a custom field to a work item type (Inheritance process), you can refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/add-custom-field?view=azure-devops) for details. After adding the custom field, you need to put value for the bug items' custom fields that already present before.